# Save graph objects in a list in R

Tags: r, igraph

I want to save several graph objects (igraph) in a list and then work with that list (calculating transitivity e.g.). Later I want to use that in a function.

```
g1<- sample_smallworld(dim=1, 1000, nei=3, p = 0.25)
g2<- sample_smallworld(dim=1, 1000, nei=3, p =0.25)
g3 <- sample_smallworld(dim=1, 1000, nei=3, p =0.25)

g <- c(g1,g2,g3)

length(g1)
length(g)
transitivity(g[1:10])
```

This was what I got:

> length(g1)
>   [1] 10
>   length(g)
>   [1] 30
>   transitivity(g[1:10])
>   Error in transitivity(g[1:10]) : Not a graph object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a list in r, it is `list()` function :

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 10
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n))

g1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Graph 1")
g2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Graph 2")
g3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Graph 3")

g <- list(g1,g2,g3)

g[[1]]
g[[2]]
g[[3]]
```

igraph object is more or less a ggplot object

Comment: Thank you! But when I try transitivity(g[1])  I still get the error message "Not a graph object"

Comment: You need to use `transitivity(g[[1]])`